# Route on select in bootstrap typeahead

Tags: angular, observable, bootstrap-typeahead

I've been working with this component here https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples.
I would like to route to a new page when a result is selected (either using enter key or click). I have the following html template. I have tried replacing the selected item function with "selectedItem($event, result), but the result in my function is undefined

```
ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">
    <div>
      <p>{{r.Name}}</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>

  <div class="keyword-wrapper">
    <input 
      type="text" 
      autocomplete="off" 
      placeholder="Search" 
      id="keyword" 
      class="form-control" 
      [formControl]="queryField" 
      [ngbTypeahead]="search" 
      [resultTemplate]="rt"
      [inputFormatter]="formatter"
      (selectItem)="selectedItem($event)"
    />
  </div>
```

selectedItem is a valid function, but I have no way of telling which result in ng-template was chosen. Is there a way to pass result in the selectItem event?

Comment: you have ng-model attached to your input element, right?

Comment: No, I'm using form control to pass the search term to a service which returns an array for the search observable. I tried to do this with ngModel, but I didn't know how to extract the value of the input field from ngModel to feed to my search service. What difference will ngModel provide me over directly linking to formControl?

Comment: David, in your function selectedItem(item:any){console.log(item)} you has the selected item